# Speakers not working properly on HP Elitebook 8440p

Tags: drivers, sound, hp, speakers

Since the 11.10 I have this problem: when I start my notebook, Speakers do not work, Whereas headphones do.
After standby and resume, Usually but not always, Everything works well.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

My Notebook specs:

```
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit (fresh installation)
HP Elitebook 8440p
```

the output of `aplay -l` is the following:

```
Lista di PLAYBACK dispositivi hardware
scheda 0: Intel [HDA Intel], dispositivo 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
  Sottoperiferiche: 0/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Put the fix in the *Answer* box below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fixed it.

I followed the instruction of the last post of this thread: 
[link](http://www.linux-archive.org/gentoo-user/566518-ff-chromium-trapped-deafness-how-configure-alsa-correctly.html) (linked by this other one: [link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/slackware-13-37-audio-setup-seems-fine-no-sound-922521/) ),

and I set the last line of alsa-base.conf as follows:

```
options snd-intel-hda model=auto,auto enable_msi=1,0 index=0,1 id=Intel,NVidia
```

After shutdown (simply rebooting does not work, I don't know why) everything seems to work fine..